# tomcat server is not starting in eclips after adding my web application

Tags: tomcat

i have developed one web application and when i try to run that application by adding it to Tomcat server i am getting error saying

```
Server Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost failed to start.
```

whereas when in start the Tomcat server individually without adding my applications it is starting without any issue.

i have tried to re-run the application by changing the server locations to Use Tomcat installation. but it was not worked and got the same error again.

can anyone please suggest your thoughts in this regard?

Comment: Can you trace log file and check...there will be description that what is cause unable to start...